# Can we have nested array of objects in couchdb?

Tags: couchdb

I have a challenge in the schema design. In a building, there should be Specific number of floors (example:10) and in every floor, I have the walls (example: 3). I assume, every wall is an object and it is a individual document. And I am mapping all these to one main document "building".

Likewise, I will have several buildings in my Database.

Comment: I don't think it is at all clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

A document in CouchDB is a JSON object. As such it can have an arbitrarily complex structure. So, yes you can have a nested array of objects. You can also have an array that stores ids of other documents. It is also common to have the child refer to the parent without the parent holding a reference to the child.

How you decompose your domain model into documents is going to depend greatly on what you want to do in your application. How are users going to interact with the data? More importantly how are multiple users going to interact with the data? In your example, what is the unit of work that the user is going to be dealing with? Would you expect multiple users to be editing the same building / floor / wall at the same time? Is it an individual's job to deal with a building, a floor, a wall?